# Pandas read_fwf

Tags: python, pandas

I am not getting a clear table.Please help.
My data are:

```
    0 2017   IX 2018       X 2018       X 2018       X 2018        0 2017   IX 2018   X 2018    X 2018   X 2018
                                                                                             0 2017       IX 2018                                    0 2017   IX 2018

    UKUPNO                                               1.053    1.075         1.093        103,8        101,7         1.633    1.669     1.701      104,2    101,9
A   Poljoprivreda, šumarstvo i ribolov                     907      888           925        102,0        104,2         1.394    1.356     1.420      101,9    104,7
B   Vađenje ruda i kamena                                  913      919           839         91,9         91,3         1.395    1.406     1.297       93,0     92,2
C   Prerađivačka industrija                                769      764           775        100,8        101,4         1.176    1.169     1.187      100,9    101,5
D   Proizvodnja i snabdijevanje                          1.574    1.570         1.647        104,6        104,9         2.459    2.455     2.579      104,9    105,1
    električnom energijom, plinom,
    parom i klimatizacija
```

I use this code:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(t), header=None, skiprows=1)
```

And I get output which I need to clean...For example I get column D separated i three columns:

```
D   Proizvodnja i snabdijevanje     1.574   1.570 1.647     104,6   104,9   2.459   2.455 2.579     104,9   105,1
13  NaN     električnom energijom, plinom,  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
14  NaN     parom i klimatizacija   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: D is not a column....? explain/show what do you want..

Comment: Sorry I mean row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the problem only with the D-"row", which has its text split into 3 rows? If so, you can do:

```
s = """
    0 2017   IX 2018       X 2018       X 2018       X 2018        0 2017   IX 2018   X 2018    X 2018   X 2018
                                                                                             0 2017       IX 2018                                    0 2017   IX 2018

    UKUPNO                                               1.053    1.075         1.093        103,8        101,7         1.633    1.669     1.701      104,2    101,9
A   Poljoprivreda, šumarstvo i ribolov                     907      888           925        102,0        104,2         1.394    1.356     1.420      101,9    104,7
B   Vađenje ruda i kamena                                  913      919           839         91,9         91,3         1.395    1.406     1.297       93,0     92,2
C   Prerađivačka industrija                                769      764           775        100,8        101,4         1.176    1.169     1.187      100,9    101,5
D   Proizvodnja i snabdijevanje                          1.574    1.570         1.647        104,6        104,9         2.459    2.455     2.579      104,9    105,1
    električnom energijom, plinom,
    parom i klimatizacija
"""

df = pd.read_fwf(pd.compat.StringIO(s), header=None, skiprows=5)

df[0] = df[0].ffill()
df[1] = df[0].map(df[1].groupby(df[0]).agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x)))
df = df.dropna(axis=0)
df
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
0   A   Poljoprivreda, šumarstvo i ribolov  907.000 888.00  925.000 102,0   104,2   1.394   1.356   1.420   101,9   104,7
1   B   Vađenje ruda i kamena   913.000 919.00  839.000 91,9    91,3    1.395   1.406   1.297   93,0    92,2
2   C   Prerađivačka industrija 769.000 764.00  775.000 100,8   101,4   1.176   1.169   1.187   100,9   101,5
3   D   Proizvodnja i snabdijevanje električnom energi...   1.574   1.57    1.647   104,6   104,9   2.459   2.455   2.579   104,9   105,1
```

Comment: Yes I want exactly like that.But I want to include number abowe:0 2017   IX 2018       X 2018 .......

Comment: Can you clarify please, include how? There are 2 rows with these numbers and at least the first row doesn't look aligned to the rest of the file

Comment: Those  number are my columns...I want to include them in my table.

Comment: OK, but if you want to use them as header, they must be aligned with the rest of the table. E.g. which column does "IX 2018" correspond to? There is no column right below

Comment: That's fine, but then you need to reformat the file first, put "IX 2018" above 1.053 etc., so that we can use it as header